# What are the - and -ip Python libraries and how can I delete them?

Tags: python, pip

```
$ pip38 list
    Package        Version
-------------- ---------
-              p
-ip            20.2.3
certifi        2020.6.20
colorpedia     1.2.0
...
```

What are the - and -ip packages and how can I uninstall them?

```
$ pip38 freeze
WARNING: Could not generate requirement for distribution -ip 20.2.3 (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages): Parse error at "'-ip==20.'": Expected W:(abcd...)
WARNING: Could not generate requirement for distribution - p (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages): Parse error at "'-===p'": Expected W:(abcd...)
certifi==2020.6.20
colorpedia==1.2.0

pip38 uninstall -
pip38 uninstall -ip
```

don't work.

Comment: Maybe just a formatting bug. `pip` could have that version. What is the output of `pip freeze`?

Comment: Yep, that totally looks like the first entry was supposed to be `pip` and the dashes are coming from the last little bit of the underline beneath `Version`.

Comment: Post modified to include result of pip freeze

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah!  Looks like a corrupt site-packages directory

```
drwxr-xr-x    8 admin  admin    256 Sep 20  2020 urllib3-1.25.10.dist-info/
drwxr-xr-x    9 admin  admin    288 Sep 20  2020 ~-p-20.2.3.dist-info/
drwxr-xr-x    9 admin  admin    288 Sep 20  2020 ~ip-20.2.3.dist-info/
```

I'm guessing a simple rm will take care of the problem